# Build if else condition against incorrect input with no semi colon

Tags: java

Hi I have parameters that I pass into an application and builds a hash map like so

```
if (text.length() > 0) {
            hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            String[] pairs = text.split(";");
            for (String pair : pairs) {
                String[] pairList = pair.split(",");
                String name = pairList[0];
                String value = pairList[1];
                hashMap.put(name, value);
            }
        }
        return hashMap;
```

The values passed in are as so

```
   String text = "Name,John;";
   String extraTest"Age,12;Location,USA;";
```

Which will build a map of <

> {Name=John, Age=12, Location=USA}>

There is various other code to concat of text1 and text2 and a lot of if else check conditions and test cases.

However I am stuck on one of my conditions (failing test case)

For instance if incorrect values are passed in with no semicolon in extraText like so

```
 String text = "Name,John;";
   String extraTest"Age,12Location,USA;";
```

it outputs as

{Name=John, Age=12Location}>

Is there anyway I can build a check agaisn't a case like above

Heres a check to concat on the text but i'm not sure how to expand it to what i want to do

```
if (!text.isEmpty() && (!extraText.isEmpty())) {
            text= text+ ";";
            text= text.concat(extraText);
```

Edit: The code needs to be able to handle the error

Comment: you mean like regular expressions?

Comment: `if(pairList.length != 2) throw new ParseException();`

Comment: Regex or not just anyway and @Ferrybig I can't get it to throw an Exception I need the code to correct any issues with input

Comment: How should the code know what the correct input is?

Comment: I know what the correct input should be e.g. the format. Name,Value;Name,Value;

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to check that the length of the array returned by the second split is exactly 2; this resolves:
a) If a comma is missing this array will be length 1
b) If a semi-colon is missing this array will be length>2

It is probably also worth checking that each 'key' value (`pairList[0]`) is not a zero length (blank) string and perhaps a minimum length on the value part too?

You might also consider checking the uniqueness of the keys as your scheme (hashset) doesn't allow duplicates.

Comment: Sometimes the pairlist isn't two though it can be one as long as the format is correct and I need to code to correct any mistakes in the input. Thanks for your input though